# How do you make chat bubble appear by click a button rather than viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, sdk, sms, chat

I don't get it. How do you make it appear by clicking a button?

```
myMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

[myMessages addObject:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 apr. 2010 13:01",@"So why do they call him \"The Joker\"?",nil]
            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"msgDate",@"msgBody",nil]]];
```

http://blog.tolik.org/2010/04/iphone-sdk-sms-balloon-cell.html

Answer (score 1):

You can start with an empty messages array to ensure that the tableview has no rows. Then, as you receive data append it to the array and call:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Stick that into an IBAction and hook it up to the button in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also the following so the table doesn't just spring into view. This will pop them in animated. use UITableViewRowAnimationTop if you want them to slide down. Also you should use a  scrollTo method so your new chat bubbles slide in and the tableview scrolls to accommodate the new information so the user doesn't have to.

```
[myTableView reloadSections:SECTION withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation];
[mytableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:INDEXPATH atScrollPosition:BOTTOM animated:YES];
```